Default Authentication scheme in ASP.NET MVC
This is the error message I'm getting:

System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultForbidScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).

The code I'm using in my controller:
if (!user.Email.Equals("my Dummy Address"))
{
    return Forbid();
}

I'm using the following code though...
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(BearerTokenDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

Why am I still getting the "No authenticationScheme was specified" error?

Found the solution...
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddBearerToken(BearerTokenDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
...
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


Try specifying the authentication scheme this way:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(ops =>{ops.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = openIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;})

And after this line var app = builder.Build(); you can add 
app.UseAuthentication();
and
app.UseAuthorization();

Where do you get openIdConnectDefaults from?  it doesn't appear to be in any packages I have imported.

I imported it from a different package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect
